# What's the best way to implement a list of elements that will have to have elements added/removed from different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I'm currently trying to implement a system list that would run in a few different threads:

1) First thread is listening to incoming requests and adds them to the list.

2) A new thread is created for each request to perform certain operations.

3) Another thread iterates through the list, checks the status of each request, and removes them from the list when they're complete.

Now, the way I have it in a very simplified pseudocode can be viewed below:

```
private List<Job> runningJobs = new ArrayList<>(); // our list of requests

private Thread monitorThread;
private Runnable monitor = new Runnable() { // this runnable is later called in a new thread to monitor the list and remove completed requests
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean monitorRun = true;
        while(monitorRun) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (runningJobs.size()>0){
                    Iterator<Job> i = runningJobs.iterator();
                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        try {
                            Job job = i.next();
                            if (job.jobStatus() == 1) { // if job is complete
                                i.remove();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    monitorRun = false;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                monitorRun = false;
            }
        }

    }
}; 

private void addRequest(Job job){
    this.runningJobs.add(newJob);
    // etc
}
```

In short, the Runnable monitor is what runs continuously in the third thread; the first thread is calling addRequest() occasionally.

While my current implementation somewhat works, I'm concerned about the order of operations here and possible java.util.ConcurrentModificationException (and the system is anything but robust). I'm certain there is a much better way to organize this mess.

What's the proper or a better way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`BlockQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation?

Comment: Frankly, I simply wasn't aware of its existence. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements would be met nicely with an `ExecutorService`. For each request, create `Job`, and submit it to the service. Internally, the service uses a `BlockingQueue`, which would address your question directly, but you don't have to worry about it with an `ExecutorService`.

Specifically, something like this:

```
/* At startup... */
ExecutorService workers = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

/* For each request... */
Job job = ... ;
workers.submit(job); /* Assuming Job implements Runnable */
// workers.submit(job::jobEntryPoint); /* If Job has some other API */

/* At shutdown... */
workers.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways.

You can synchronize the list.  This is possibly the most brute-force and still wouldn't help prevent an insert while you are iterating over it.

There are a few synchronized* collections.  These tend to be better but have ramifications.  For instance CopyOnWriteArrayList will work but it creates a new array list each time (that you would assign back to the variable).  This is good for occasionally updated collections.

There is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue--Since it's "Linked" you can't reference an item in the middle.

Look through the implementations of the "List" interface and pick the one that best suits your problem.

If your problem is a queue instead of a list, there are a few implementations of that as well and they will tend to be better suited for that type of problem.

In general my answer is that you should probably scan through the Javadocs every time java does a major release and examine (at least) the new collections.  You might be surprised at the stuff that's in there.